# Series expansion is separately expanding numerator and denominator

Tags: series-expansion

I am trying to expand a function in power series, but Mathematica is expanding the numerator and the denominator separately.

```
Series[-((
  0.0435275 (18 - 20 Cos[ky] + 2 Cos[2 ky]))/((1 - 
     Cos[ky])^0.2 (3.03143 (1 - Cos[ky])^1.6 + Sin[ky]^2)^(
   3/2))), {ky, 0, 6}]
```

The output is

```
SeriesData[ky, 0, {-0.2999998058828007, 0, -0.029999980588280066`, 0, 
  0.006999995470598682}, 2, 7, 1]/((ky^2)^0.2 ((
SeriesData[ky, 0, {1, 0, 
Rational[-1, 3], 0, 
Rational[2, 45]}, 2, 7, 1]) + (ky^2)^1.6 (
SeriesData[
     ky, 0, {0.9999989664885686, 0., -0.13333319553180914`, 0., 
      0.007777769739355534, 0., -0.00026454999113454205`}, 0, 7, 
      1]))^(3/2))
```

How do I expand the function as a power series about `ky = 0`?
Note: The function diverges at ky = 0, and ky is a real quantity.

Comment: Use rational exponents, e.g., `(1 - Cos[k y])^(8/5)`, and specify `Assumptions -> ky >0` or `Assumptions -> ky \[Element] Reals` in the `Series` function.

Comment: @CarlWoll That works, please write it as an answer and I will accept it

Comment: By the way, what is the best method to post such complicated output, which are hard to visualize after copy pasting (e.g. the function above)?